# Directory listing in IBM 4690 CBASIC

Tags: directory, adx

I'm looking for the correct ADX call to perform a directory listing of a Controller drive. From the IBM programming guide, I see ADX_TDIR, which is for terminals, is there a variant for controller program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make use of quote command `dir -s` using adxstart function and save it to an output file.